# Docker error while copying jar from maven target directory

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I'm building Docker image to run Spring Boot, but while building it i get error about copying `jar` file from target directory:

`failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount188888512/var/www/app/target: no such file or directory`

Here's the `backend.Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:17

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN ./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip

EXPOSE 8080

COPY var/www/app/target/*.jar app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Here's the part of `docker-compose.yaml` responsible for SpringBoot container:

```
app:
  container_name: app
  build:
    dockerfile: ./docker/backend.Dockerfile
  restart: on-failure
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
    - mysql
    - mail-catcher
```

And the project structure:

```
.
├── docker
│   └── backend.Dockerfile
├── src
│   └──...
├── target
│   └──...
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
└── docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: The left-hand side of `COPY` is a relative path that will always be underneath the build-context directory.  There's not a `var/www` directory on your host; do you just need to `COPY target/*.jar ./app.jar`?

Comment: `COPY` command copies files from `host` to `container`, in your case you actually need to copy file from one directory to another within container, so, replace `COPY var/www/app/target/*.jar app.jar` with `RUN cp /var/www/app/target/*.jar app.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend another way of building your docker images with Spring Boot Project.

You can refer to this example by using the maven plugin during the maven build, your image will be built. The plugin comes from org.springframework.boot and it will help you build the image for the required module. You would need to use it in your pom.xml file if it is a maven project.

Then you could just run 'mvn clean install' if you have any test that you want to be run as well, or if you want your tests to be skipped you can use 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'

The image will be built in a layered format of docker, in a multistage image build format.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>ms/product.service:latest</name>
                </image>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-image</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What parts of `backend.Dockerimage` should i replace with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`?

Comment: @karixdev you do not need to replace anything. You would have to go to the pom.xml file of the project, paste the code that I showed above, in the <name> </name> properties put the name which you want to name the docker image. Then after you do this do a refresh maven inside the file. Once you are done with this, run mvn clean install -DSkipTests and you image will be multi-stage built automatically. Let me know if you need further help.